# Converting Base64 String to PictureBox

Tags: c#, sql-server, image, winforms, base64

Im able to convert an `image` into Base64. But now im trying to convert it back and store it in a `PictureBox`

```
var pic = Convert.FromBase64String(product.Picture);

using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new System.IO.MemoryStream(pic)))
{ 
      //NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE
      pictureBox1.Image =????;
}
```

Edit 1;
Firstly Thanks to everyone, i have tried all the solutions below and they all work. But i have multiple images, What if there is no image in `Poduct.Picture`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to use something like:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pic))
{
     pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 // Convert base 64 string to byte[]
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
// Convert byte[] to Image
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
{
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
}
```

Comment: im getting a red X in a box , where the image should be?

Comment: I fixed it using  `PictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)image.Clone();`

Answer (score 1):

just do it like this:

```
var pic = Convert.FromBase64String(product.Picture);

using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new  System.IO.MemoryStream(pic)))
{ 
  //NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE
  pictureBox1.Image =image;
}
```